# Freeing linked structs in C

Tags: c, data-structures, memory-management, struct, free

Okay so I have a Binary Search Tree built using only C structs and pointers because I'm insane and didn't want to use C++.  Anyways, I've got some serious memory leaks since I'm ***assuming*** `free(tree)`, tree being an instance of the struct below, doesn't free all the children of that tree.

Here is my node:

```
struct node{
    struct node* parent;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
    int key; //the value of the node
};
```

and here is my bst:

```
struct bst{
    struct node* root;
    int elements; //number of nodes in the bst
};
```

So my question, is there any better way of doing this than recursively calling a delete function?  for instance (writing this on the spot):

```
void delete_tree(struct node* n){
    if(n == NULL) return;
    struct node* left = n->left;
    struct node* right = n->right;
    free(n);
    delete_tree(left);
    delete_tree(right);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see absolutely nothing wrong with a recursive delete. You could use an iterative approach, but it wouldn't have any discernible benefits and would be harder to write.

By the way, you can simplify the code a little and remove the two local variables as so:

```
void delete_tree(struct node* n){
    if(n == NULL) return;
    delete_tree(n->left);
    delete_tree(n->right);
    free(n);
}
```

Comment: that's the only way to do it? no fancy hidden secret that would make this be a "reinventing the wheel" kind of situation?

Comment: I'm sure there are other ways, I just don't see any particular reason why they'd be better. And this is really easy to write correctly which is a big plus point to me.

Comment: @Greg: Well, you *could* use an iterative approach, too, but in any case, you'll have to touch each node once to find and delete child nodes and a recursive solution is readable and easy to verify/maintain, just as David said.

Comment: @Greg Flynn- Nope, C doesn't have any sort of recursive "self-destruct" capability like that.  You have to write it yourself.  Your code is fairly close as-is, just add a line that frees `n` after the two recursive calls to `delete_tree` return.

Comment: @Greg Flynn - not the only way, but very easy and not much you can actually improve in that.

Comment: Or you can use a library that has higher-level structures like [glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/) if you don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Greg By the way, if you write the free after the recursive calls to delete_tree then you don't need those pesky locals - see my update

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses and valuable input!

Comment: One reason to be wary of recursive delete here is if the tree isn't balanced - then you could be using a lot of stack. But an unbalanced tree isn't very good at the "searching" part of BST, so this isn't the only thing you might be worried about in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You are making the recursive calls but never actually call `free`. You probably need to verify if a node is a leaf node (maybe asking if both children are null) and call `free` on that node.

Comment: `if(n == NULL) return;` checks for leaves